# Array vs If, which one is better in performance/best practice sight?

Tags: arrays, if-statement, optimization

For same result I can use (I prefer this simple one, personally):

```
$idx = 2;
$arr = ["Sun", "Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat"];
echo $arr[$idx];
```

or:

```
$idx = 2;
if ($idx == 0)
    echo "Sun";
elseif ($idx == 1)
    echo "Mon";
elseif ($idx == 2)
    echo "Tue";
elseif ($idx == 3)
    echo "Wed";
elseif ($idx == 4)
    echo "Thu";
elseif ($idx == 5)
    echo "Fri";
else
    echo "Sat";
```

Which one is better in performance or best practice perspective?

Comment: What programming language ?

Comment: IT will be different for different languages depends on implementation, how ever this scenrio my preference will be array one

Answer (score 0):

I think array is faster. Array are reference object, so when you use array[index], it will get the value without loop from 0 to index.

When you use if else like  that, it just like the loop:

```js
$idx = 5;
for($i =0;i<$array.length;i++)
{
    if(i==idx){
      echo ($array[i]);
break;
    }
}
```

Comment: what about memory used by the array?

Comment: array is not large too much to think about memory. Bigger memory is not mean slower.

Comment: Dear maspai, create new question.

Comment: I think it's still relevant with this thread, questioning array vs if in performance perspective